# Direct native JavaScript or jQuery method to get containing block of an element

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a built-in DOM API or a jquery one to get the *[containing block](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Containing_block)* of an element?

I am not asking how to get the containing block of an element. I am just asking if there's already the wheel so I don't have to re-invent it. If there isn't, I could just do:

```
let containingBlock = $("#five")
                      .parents()
                      .find(parent => parent.css("position") === ...);
```

for the following HTML, for example:

```
<div id = "one">
    <div id = "two" style = "position: absolute;">
        <div id = "three">
            <div id = "four">
                <div id = "five" style = "position: absolute;"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: How about JQuery [.parent()](https://api.jquery.com/parent) instead of `.parents()`?

Comment: To both the commentators (KIKO Software and Abana Clara), the parent is not the same as the *containing block*. The question is not how to get a reference to the parent element of an HTML element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `offsetParent()` to get the closest parent element that is positioned. According to [the documentation](https://api.jquery.com/offsetParent/), it works when the parent element is positioned `absolute`, `relative`, or `fixed`, but it also worked with `sticky` positioning for me.

Comment: Wow! Thank you. Just what I was after.

Answer (score 3):

Take care: a parent with any of

- A `transform` or perspective value other than none
- A `will-change` value of transform or perspective
- A `filter` value other than none or a `will-change` value of filter (only works on Firefox).
- A `contain` value of paint (e.g. contain: paint;)

and also a parent with `backdrop-filter` (I found the hard way) will also become a containing block.

references: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Containing_block