# How can I get the containing block of a "fixed" positioned element with javascript?

Tags: javascript, css-position

Let's say we have the following setup:

```css
#header {
    background-color: #ddd;
    padding: 2rem;
}
#containing-block {
    background-color: #eef;
    padding: 2rem;
    height: 70px;
    transform: translate(0, 0);
}
#button {
    position: fixed;
    top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">header</div>
<div id="containing-block">
    containing-block
    <div>
      <div>
        <div>
          <button id="button" onclick="console.log('offsetParent', this.offsetParent)">click me</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

where the button has `fixed` position and the containing-block has a `transform` property in place.

This might come as a surprise, but the button is positioned relative to the `#containing-block`, not the viewport (as one would expect when using `fixed`). That's because the `#containing-block` element has the `transform` property set. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#fixed for clarification.

Is there an easy way to find out which is the containing block of the button? Which is the element `top: 50px` is calculated in respect to? Assume you don't have a reference to the containing block and you don't know how many levels up it is. It may even be the documentElement if there are no ancestors with `transform`, `perspective` or `filter` properties set.

For `absolute` or `relative` positioned elements, we have `elem.offsetParent` which gives us this reference. However, it is set to null for `fixed` elements.

Of course, I could look up the dom and find the first element that has a style property of `transform`, `perspective` or `filter` set, but this seems hacky and not future proof.

Thanks!

Comment: On Firefox, `offsetParent` is returning the right value. Chrome and other browsers are reporting `null` but it seems to be a bug. I filed a bug report https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1086125

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Known behavior and spec compliant.  spec should probably be changed though.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetParent

I've included a few workarounds from various libraries.

Workaround taken from dom-helpers (seems to be most consistent and use of offsetParent to traverse means it should only ever really traverse once or twice.):
https://github.com/react-bootstrap/dom-helpers/blob/master/src/offsetParent.ts

```js
// taken from popper.js
function getStyleComputedProperty(element, property) {
  if (element.nodeType !== 1) {
    return [];
  }
  // NOTE: 1 DOM access here
  const window = element.ownerDocument.defaultView;
  const css = window.getComputedStyle(element, null);
  return property ? css[property] : css;
}

getOffsetParent = function(node) {
  const doc = (node && node.ownerDocument) || document
  const isHTMLElement = e => !!e && 'offsetParent' in e
  let parent = node && node.offsetParent

  while (
    isHTMLElement(parent) &&
    parent.nodeName !== 'HTML' &&
    getComputedStyle(parent, 'position') === 'static'
  ) {
    parent = parent.offsetParent
  }

  return (parent || doc.documentElement)
}
```

```css
#header {
    background-color: #ddd;
    padding: 2rem;
}
#containing-block {
    background-color: #eef;
    padding: 2rem;
    height: 70px;
    transform: translate(0, 0);
}
#button {
    position: fixed;
    top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">header</div>
    <div id="containing-block">
        containing-block
        <div>
          <div>
            <div>
              <button id="button" onclick="console.log('offsetParent', getOffsetParent(this),this.offsetParent)">click me</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Workaround code taken from jQuery source.  Doesn't deal with non-element, nor TABLE TH TD, but it's *jQuery*.
https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/offset.js

```js
// taken from popper.js
function getStyleComputedProperty(element, property) {
  if (element.nodeType !== 1) {
    return [];
  }
  // NOTE: 1 DOM access here
  const window = element.ownerDocument.defaultView;
  const css = window.getComputedStyle(element, null);
  return property ? css[property] : css;
}

getOffsetParent = function(elem) {
  var doc = elem.ownerDocument;
  var offsetParent = elem.offsetParent || doc.documentElement;
  while (offsetParent &&
    (offsetParent !== doc.body || offsetParent !== doc.documentElement) &&
    getComputedStyle(offsetParent, "position") === "static") {

    offsetParent = offsetParent.parentNode;
  }
  return offsetParent;
}
```

```css
#header {
    background-color: #ddd;
    padding: 2rem;
}
#containing-block {
    background-color: #eef;
    padding: 2rem;
    height: 70px;
    transform: translate(0, 0);
}
#button {
    position: fixed;
    top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">header</div>
    <div id="containing-block">
        containing-block
        <div>
          <div>
            <div>
              <button id="button" onclick="console.log('offsetParent', getOffsetParent(this),this.offsetParent)">click me</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Workaround code taken from popper.js.  Doesn't seem to get doc.body right.  The only one that specifically deals with TH TD TABLE.  dom-helpers should work just because it uses offsetParent to traverse.
https://github.com/popperjs/popper-core/blob/master/src/dom-utils/getOffsetParent.js

```js
var isBrowser = typeof window !== 'undefined' && typeof document !== 'undefined' && typeof navigator !== 'undefined';

const isIE11 = isBrowser && !!(window.MSInputMethodContext && document.documentMode);
const isIE10 = isBrowser && /MSIE 10/.test(navigator.userAgent);
function isIE(version) {
  if (version === 11) {
    return isIE11;
  }
  if (version === 10) {
    return isIE10;
  }
  return isIE11 || isIE10;
}

function getStyleComputedProperty(element, property) {
  if (element.nodeType !== 1) {
    return [];
  }
  // NOTE: 1 DOM access here
  const window = element.ownerDocument.defaultView;
  const css = window.getComputedStyle(element, null);
  return property ? css[property] : css;
}

function getOffsetParent(element) {
  if (!element) {
    return document.documentElement;
  }

  const noOffsetParent = isIE(10) ? document.body : null;

  // NOTE: 1 DOM access here
  let offsetParent = element.offsetParent || null;
  // Skip hidden elements which don't have an offsetParent
  while (offsetParent === noOffsetParent && element.nextElementSibling) {
    offsetParent = (element = element.nextElementSibling).offsetParent;
  }

  const nodeName = offsetParent && offsetParent.nodeName;

  if (!nodeName || nodeName === 'BODY' || nodeName === 'HTML') {
    return element ? element.ownerDocument.documentElement : document.documentElement;
  }

  // .offsetParent will return the closest TH, TD or TABLE in case
  // no offsetParent is present, I hate this job...
  if (['TH', 'TD', 'TABLE'].indexOf(offsetParent.nodeName) !== -1 && getStyleComputedProperty(offsetParent, 'position') === 'static') {
    return getOffsetParent(offsetParent);
  }

  return offsetParent;
}
```

```css
#header {
    background-color: #ddd;
    padding: 2rem;
}
#containing-block {
    background-color: #eef;
    padding: 2rem;
    height: 70px;
    transform: translate(0, 0);
}
#button {
    position: fixed;
    top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">header</div>
<div id="containing-block">
    containing-block
    <div>
      <div>
        <div>
          <button id="button" onclick="console.log('offsetParent', getOffsetParent(this))">click me</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I recently crafted what I feel to be a rather elegant workaround to this not-so-little, long-standing quirk. I've designed a [CustomElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_custom_elements) that can automatically detect if it has been used inside of a containing block and, if so, shift itself from it's current location in the DOM to the end of the body element.

Credit to this answer to a similar question for pointing me in the right direction. https://stackoverflow.com/a/65155438/6036546

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<title> Breakout Fixed </title>
<script type="module">
  customElements.define(
    'breakout-fixed',
    
    class BreakoutFixed extends HTMLElement {
      constructor() {
        super();
        this.attachShadow({ mode : 'open' });
        this.shadowRoot.innerHTML = this.template;
      }
      
      get template() {
        return `
          <style> :host { position: fixed; } </style>
          <slot></slot>
        `; 
      }
      
      breakout() {
        const el = this;

        if (this.fixed !== true) {
          window.addEventListener('resize', el.fix);
          this.fixed = true;
        }
        
        if (el.parentNode == document.body) { return; }

        function shift() {
          getContainingBlock(el) &&
            document.body.append(el);
        }

        function getContainingBlock(node) {
          if (node.parentElement) {
            if (node.parentElement == document.body) {
              return document.body;
            } else if (testNode(node.parentElement) == false) {
              return getContainingBlock(node.parentElement);
            } else { return node.parentElement; }
          } else { return null; }
          function testNode(node) {
            let test; let cs = getComputedStyle(node);
            test = cs.getPropertyValue('position'); if ([
              'absolute', 'fixed'
            ].includes(test)) { return true; }
            test = cs.getPropertyValue('transform');   if (test != 'none')  { return true; }
            test = cs.getPropertyValue('perspective'); if (test != 'none')  { return true; }
            test = cs.getPropertyValue('perspective'); if (test != 'none')  { return true; }
            test = cs.getPropertyValue('filter');      if (test != 'none')  { return true; }
            test = cs.getPropertyValue('contain');     if (test == 'paint') { return true; }
            test = cs.getPropertyValue('will-change'); if ([
              'transform', 'perspective', 'filter'
            ].includes(test)) { return true; }
            return false;
          }
        }
      }
      
      connectedCallback() {
        this.breakout();
      }
    }
  );
</script>
<style>
  body { background: dimgrey; }
  
  #container {
    height: 300px;
    width: 50%;
    background: dodgerblue;
    transform: scale(2);
  }
  
  div#test {
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    padding: 1rem;
    background: red;
  }
  
  breakout-fixed {
    top: 0; right: 0;
    padding: 1rem;
    background: limegreen;
    transform: scale(3);
    transform-origin: top right;
  }
</style>
<div id="container">
  <div id="test"> This element will be fixed to it's containing block. </div>
  <breakout-fixed>
    <div> This element will be fixed to the viewport. </div>
  </breakout-fixed>
</div>
```

Comment: There is a typo in the will-change check, `filer` instead of `filter`

Comment: Good catch, thanks! I've updated the code and also added a window resize handler in case media query changes cause a containing block to be created (for example using scale() in a responsive design). There are probably other cases I haven't covered but this should be a good base for anyone looking to overcome this strange browser behavior.